# How to echo the_title from an array of posts?

Tags: php, query-posts

I'm trying to query wordpress post by using `query_posts` and trying to save them in an array so that I get retrieve the post from array. This is what I'm doing,

```
    $posts =array();
    $args = array('posts_per_page' =>3,'cat' => 3 );
    $posts[] = query_posts( $args );

    global $post;
    if ( ! empty($posts) ) :
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);  
        echo get_the_title();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
```

When I run this script it shows a post which is not in `cat` 3. but if I do `print_r($post)` it shows the correct three posts. Any idea of where I'm getting wrong?

Answer (score 1):

try to use get_posts instead , as I read in http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

you can use this code:

```
global $post;
$args = array('posts_per_page' =>3,'category' => 3 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $myposts as $post ) :
  setup_postdata($post); 
  the_title()
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Regard's.

Comment: I'm trying to put the posts into an array as you can see in my code I've used `$posts = array()` and `$posts[]` and that's because I'd run multiple queries and get posts out of them

Comment: as you can see get_posts function return the posts array you want($myposts)

Comment: Use `get_the_title( $post->ID )` instead. No need for `setup_postdata` either.

Answer (score 0):

[`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)  clobbers the `global` variable `$wp_query`. Don't use it:

> Note: This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As
>   explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter
>   the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way
>   to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of
>   the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright
>   fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts
>   pagination). Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods, like
>   making use of pre_get_posts hook, for this purpose.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Note the very first line: "***This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes.***"

Someone has already mentioned `get_posts()`, which is perfectly valid. However, I tend to prefer `WP_Query` for just about everything related to post retrieval, so I'd lean toward something like:

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'cat' => 1 
);
$cp = new WP_Query( $args );
foreach ($cp->posts as $p) {
  echo apply_filters('the_title',$p->post_title);
}
```